# Adding .so files to jniLibs in Android Studio: duplicate files during packaging of APK

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

Following various sets of instructions, it seems that I should add native libraries to `app/src/main/jniLibs` and they'll be linked up automagically. However when I do this (for OpenCV) I get the following:

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK /.../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: lib/armeabi/libopencv_java.so
    Origin 1: /.../app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libopencv_java.so
    Origin 2: /.../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/AppName/.libraries/opencv/unspecified/jni/armeabi/libopencv_java.so
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libopencv_java.so'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi/libopencv_java.so
    File 1: /.../app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libopencv_java.so
    File 2: /.../app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libopencv_java.so
```

Adding the `exclude` section doesn't work. There's only one copy of the file, but somehow it's being referenced twice, and it seems the second (`build`) include is something auto-generated. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndk-build` was generating duplicates of all of the packages from OpenCV. I removed all of the `.so` libraries from my app, apart from my actual app library, and then it packaged up fine.

Answer (score 5):

In case of duplicate libraries (*.so) files, exclude option will not help as we cannot completely exclude the native binaries. There is one more option in packagingOptions. It is 'pickFirst'. We can avoid duplicate files error and include the first one the compiler encounters.

```
packagingOptions {    
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libopencv_java.so'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. It seems it's because the documentation and various conversation threads on setting up OpenCV for Android say to put the JNI libraries at the path /src/main/jniLibs or /src/main/libs. The problem is that the /src/ folder is for source code, not libraries. The solution is to move the /main/ folder out of /src/ and into the project root, which is how Google documents this project structure: https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

I also have the following settings in build.gradle:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
            jniLibs.srcDir 'main/libs'
        }
    }
}
```